# How to properly make a session token verification on reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I'm building a website using the Next.js framework and I wanted to know if there is any way for me to stop the reload effect from entering the login page (happens on the fraction of a second) before going back to the main page.

Here is the current code I have for that page.

```
const Home: React.FC<any> = ({ jsonHydration, contextHydration }) => {
  const [isUserLoggedIn, setIsUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["session_key"]);
  const session_key = cookies.session_key;

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsUserLoggedIn(!!session_key)
  }, [session_key]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unloadCallback = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; returnValue: string; }) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "";
      return "";
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  }, []);

  function handleLogin(session_key: number) {
    setCookie("session_key", session_key, { path: "/", maxAge: 3600 });
  }

  if (isUserLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
          <JsonStoreProvider hydrationData={jsonHydration}>
            <StoresProvider hydrationData={contextHydration}>
              <MainLayout/>
            </StoresProvider>
          </JsonStoreProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
        <JsonStoreProvider hydrationData={jsonHydration}>
          <StoresProvider hydrationData={contextHydration}>
            <LoginPage onLogin={handleLogin} />
          </StoresProvider>
        </JsonStoreProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    )
  }
};
```

I've searched on some posts and this was the closest I could get to my initial objective of maintaining the user on the main page when login in with a valid session key. The way this is working now is basically entering both pages on reload, running once, entering the login page and then the useEffect() kicks in and updates de variables isUserLoggedIn to 1 so it goes to the main page. This not only makes a "fresh start", ignoring what the stores had before, and also makes that login page micro second display. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code. It is okay to have two useEffects.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unloadCallback = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; returnValue: string; }) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "";
      return "";
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  }, []);
```

this loads only once since you are passing empty array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsUserLoggedIn(!!session_key)
  }, [session_key]);
```

I am assuming your CookieProvider in the below code

```
if (isUserLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
          <JsonStoreProvider hydrationData={jsonHydration}>
            <StoresProvider hydrationData={contextHydration}>
              <MainLayout/>
            </StoresProvider>
          </JsonStoreProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
        <JsonStoreProvider hydrationData={jsonHydration}>
          <StoresProvider hydrationData={contextHydration}>
            <LoginPage onLogin={handleLogin} />
          </StoresProvider>
        </JsonStoreProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    )
  }
```

is dealing with setting cookies after logging in.

Can you refactor your code to below:

```
const Home: React.FC<any> = ({ jsonHydration, contextHydration }) => {
  const [isUserLoggedIn, setIsUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["session_key"]);
  const session_key = cookies.session_key;

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsUserLoggedIn(!!session_key)
  }, [session_key]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unloadCallback = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; returnValue: string; }) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "";
      return "";
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  }, []);

  function handleLogin(session_key: number) {
    setCookie("session_key", session_key, { path: "/", maxAge: 3600 });
  }

    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
        <JsonStoreProvider hydrationData={jsonHydration}>
          <StoresProvider hydrationData={contextHydration}>
            { isUserLoggedIn ? <MainLayout/> : <LoginPage onLogin={handleLogin} />}
          </StoresProvider>
        </JsonStoreProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    )
  }
};
```

I refactored `if` block to a simple ternary operator and avoided `cookieprovider` to load twice. Because you are loading `CookieProvider` seperately using `if` block, that is somehow triggering `useEffect` depending on `session_key`

Please let me know if the above refactored code worked for you, otherwise, I would further investigate your `CookieProvider` code.

Comment: Hi @Ramu, first of all thanks for the quick reply. Tried your suggestion with no success unfortunately... Relative to the CookiesProvider it comes from the react-cookie library. 
"import { CookiesProvider, useCookies } from "react-cookie";"

It still goes through that useEffect right aftert the refresh and displays the login at a glance

Comment: Can you share the code for your Login component? Let me see the cookies you are setting when the user logs in.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The way I setup the cookies is on function handleLogin() as you can see in the code above, all I retrieve from the login page is the session key that my API returns. So all I do on the login page is onLogin(session_key).

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are passing handleLogin as a prop. Can you configure a codesandbox and share the link? I will see what I can do.